# Credible vs Credulous. Is their meaning similar or contradictory?

Tags: meaning, ambiguity

I was taking a Wonderlic test and got somewhat confused by one of the questions. The question was:

> CREDIBLE CREDULOUS - Do these words...
>
> [] Have similar meanings
>   [] Have contradictory meanings
>   [] Have unrelated meanings

Now, I do know the definition of each word. Credible means trustworthy, easily believed by others. Credulous means gullible, easily believes others. But are these meanings similar (both have to do with one person believing another) or opposite (everyone believes you vs you believe everyone)?
I feel like either answer could be easily argued both for and against, but as a non-native English speaker maybe I'm just missing something. They are neither synonyms nor antonyms, so what's the best answer?

Comment: A credulous source is also a non-credible one, because how could you rely on a person's information if they had just picked it up from any old place?  So I'd say contradictory.  I wouldn't say unrelated, because they're both connected to 'belief' - but I wouldn't say similar, either.

Comment: The best answer is "Who the **** wrote this stupid test and what the **** were they thinking??".  :-)  Seriously, it's a junk question.

Comment: @Hellion I'm not sure who wrote it, but it was an official supervised Mensa test at my university.

Comment: Are you allowed to check all three options, or is it strictly "pick one"?

Comment: @Hellion The instructions said that it's a standard multiple-choice test and to only pick one answer. But who knows, it's supposed to be an IQ test so maybe defying instructions and picking more than one answer WAS the right answer :D

Comment: @Helion I agree that it is a junk question. If a person known to be quite truthful but generally credulous said that he slept in this morning, that statement would be credible because his general credulity would not affect his specific knowledge related to that statement.

Comment: True, I don't dispute that it's a junk question.  The whole idea of multi-choice tests is absurd, because there's often an argument for more than one of the answers, and even where there isn't, someone might have picked the wrong answer for a valid reason and another person might have picked at random.  I assume that multi-choice tests were invented to reduce the workload of examiners rather than to improve the quality of examinations.

Comment: @rjpond I agree about the idiocy of multiple choice in anything that is not in mathematics or (perhaps) in the "hard" sciences. And this question is a good example of that idiocy: either "contradictory" or "not related" are arguable approximations of correct answers.

Comment: @rjpond It *is* possible to write good multiple choice answers on topics like logic, but it is HARD. For example, [LSAC writes a very tight test, but their process for writing answers includes many stages of editing and re-writing and testing the test questions](http://lsatblog.blogspot.com/2011/08/being-lsat-testmaker-interview.html). I doubt this test went through anything like that kind of vetting.

Comment: Being "credible" (or not) is a property of a claim or of a person making a claim.  Being "credulous" (or not) is a property of an audience of a claim.  I would like to turn this into an answer, but for some reason, which I am not understanding, this question has been closed.

Answer (score 1):

They have related meanings. Both derive from the Latin root "cred," meaning "believe." Both words thus relate to believing. They are neither synonyms nor antonyms.

"Credible" means "worthy of belief." It implies both honesty and knowledge.

"Credulous" means "of a believing disposition" and thus "easy to fool" or "gullible." It does not imply dishonesty.

In certain contexts, the two words become quasi-antonyms because a credulous person may believe a great deal that is incorrect and so not be credible.

"A, who is credible, said X" implies that X is probably true.

"B, who is credulous", said Y" implies that Y may be incorrect.

But they are not true antonyms because "credible" implies honesty whereas "credulous" does not imply dishonesty.

EDIT: I forgot another difference. "Credulous" refers to people. "Credible" may refer to people, but may also refer to statements.